# Formatear valor numérico

Tags: c#

Se que este debe ser un tema recurrente acá, pero no he dado con la forma que necesito.

Estoy usando `.ToString(new CultureInfo("es-CL")` para mostrar valores con separación de miles, pero me trae dos decimales que no necesito mostrar, la línea completa es la siguiente:

```
hoja.MontoLiquido = usrReneg.Rutero[0].montoLiquido.ToString(new CultureInfo("es-CL"));

//25.021,00
```

¿Qué necesito agregarle para que el valor me salga como lo necesito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `ToString` tiene diferentes sobrecargas, puedes especificar el tipo y precisión, además de la localización ([documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)).

Por lo que para mostrar un valor numérico sin decimales, puedes utilizar lo siguiente:

```
hoja.MontoLiquido = usrReneg.Rutero[0].montoLiquido.ToString("N0", new CultureInfo("es-CL"));
```

El parámetro "N0" indica que deseas mostrar un valor numérico sin ningún decimal.